# Numerically greatest coefficient in a multinomial expression

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients

> Given the expression $E=(1+3x+8x^2)^{12}$ .
>   I was trying to find the numerically greatest coefficient of any power of x in the above expression.

**My try**

I wrote the general coefficient as

$(10)! (3^p)(8^q)/{(p!)(q!)(10-p-q)!} $
However I am unable to maximise this expression.
 I was hoping for some hints or an alternate solution ?